# react-query useQuery typescript No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm trying the react query tutorial with typescript, but when fetching data the errors occurred.

**code:**

```
type heroType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  alterEgo: string;
};

function QueryDataFetch() {
  const fetchdata = ()=>{ return axios.get("http://localhost:8000/superheroes")}
  const { isLoading, data ,error} = useQuery<heroType[]>(["heros"],fetchdata);
```

this error red unline shows at **fetchdata**

**data:**

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Batman",
"alterEgo": "Bruce Wayne"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Superman",
"alterEgo": "Clark Kent"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Wonder Woman",
"alterEgo": "Princess Diana"
}
]
```

**error:**

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '() => Promise<AxiosResponse<any, any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFunction<heroType[], QueryKey>'.
Failed to compile.
```

I have no idea how to fix it.

**resolve:**

```
  const fetchdata = async (): Promise<heroType[]> => {
    const payload = await axios
      .get("http://localhost:8000/superheroes")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.data;
      });
    return payload;
  };
```

after TkDodo help, add Promise and reture value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

axios returns something that is of type `AxiosResponse`, but you tell react-query that you expect something of type `heroType[]`. That is not the same. Axios wraps everything into an object that has `data` and `headers` and some other options, and only the `data` is the actual json that is returned from your api. So you need to unwrap it:

```
const fetchdata = async (): Promise<heroType[]> => {
  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/superheroes")}
  return response.data
}

const { isLoading, data ,error} = useQuery(["heros"], fetchdata);
```

Also, it's usually better to add type annotations to your fetch function instead of adding generics to useQuery, because it will contain your error to where it actually comes from.